# 'USE db_name' takes too long to change when login remotely

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I gave `SELECT` privilege to a user on a particular database, Now whenever I try to connect remotely

```
$ mysql -h ip-of-remote -u username -p
```

with that user credentials and try to change the database it takes to long to get **Database changed** while it connects (goes mysql prompt) very fast

```
mysql> USE db_name;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql>
```

On the contrary, when I ssh the mysql server and then try to login mysql prompt locally (without host) with the same user credentials and then try to change database it quickly changes and I don't get that message

```
mysql> USE db_name;
Database changed
mysql>
```

---

I tried to  `--disable-auto-rehash` in my.cnf but no luck. Please help

```
[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
```

Comment: Did you try `$ mysql -A -h ip-of-remote -u username -p`?

Comment: On doing that I don't get the delay and that message. But I can't recommend that to every user to append `-A` every time. I need something at the server configuration level

Comment: I see, then you should restart the server after adding `no-auto-rehash` to the cnf file

Comment: Already restarted after making those changes

Comment: I'd guess your database host tries to resolve your IP address to a host name or vice versa because of privileges attached to hosts. Wild guess, but you might want to check your DNS setup and/or use ip-addresses/host names when granting privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the the following command `use my_database;` executed too fast when you try this locally (on the same server), and take a log time when you executed remotely, there is some common causes for that like the connection between the server and client is slow, or there is a delay (lag) on attempting to retrieve and verify reverse `DNS`, you can try to add the following parameter `skip_name_resolve` for testing to `my.ini` or `my.cnf` under `[mysqld]` section.